# no permissions error on adb devices

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

Every time I reboot my Ubuntu 17.10 machine I get this error when I run `adb devices`:

```
List of devices attached
8XV7N15A20003222    no permissions (verify udev rules); see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]
```

And to fix it all I do is run:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

And then I unplug the phone and plug it back in because flipping usb debug on and off on the settings isn't enough. Unplugging and plugging back in doesn't fix it unless I run that command.

What can I do to fix this permanently? This is a Nexus 6P.

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate because restarting adb doesn't fix it like on that linked post. I've also already edited the udev rules.

Edit: One more thing, this only happens to my 6P. I have several other phones connected (Nexus 6,4,5, some samsung, motorola, etc) and none of them have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add permission. Try: `adb root`. I hope it will work.

Comment: So right now the permissions of adb are myuser:myuser, should I make it myuser:root?